# whole viewgroup to bitmap

Tags: android, android-layout, view, android-widget

Is it possible to get a full bitmap from a viewgroup-object?

This code takes a 'screenshot' off the view group that's currently on the screen, but I want the whole view, also what's not currently on the screen.

```
public void export(ViewGroup view){
    view.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
    view.setDrawingCacheQuality(View.DRAWING_CACHE_QUALITY_HIGH);
    Bitmap bitmap = view.getDrawingCache(true);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here I used ScrollView to get the whole view to bitmap
so Here u can use instead of scrollview anyother view group like linerlayout etc..

```
    Bitmap map = loadBitmapFromView(getApplicationContext(),scrollView);
            ByteArrayOutputStream bytes = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            map.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, bytes);

            //you can create a new file name "test.jpg" in sdcard folder.
            File f = new File("/sdcard" +"/" + "mainemailpdf.jpg");
            f.createNewFile();
            //write the bytes in file
            FileOutputStream fo = new FileOutputStream(f);
            fo.write(bytes.toByteArray());
            bArray = bytes.toByteArray();
            // remember close de FileOutput
            fo.close();
```

and for loadBitmapFromView method is:

```
public static Bitmap loadBitmapFromView(Context context, View v) {

        Toast.makeText(context,
                v.getMeasuredHeight() + "::::::::::::" + v.getMeasuredWidth(),
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        if (v.getMeasuredHeight() > 0) {

            v.measure(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

            Bitmap b = Bitmap.createBitmap(v.getWidth(), v.getHeight(),
                    Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);

            Canvas c = new Canvas(b);

            v.layout(0, 0, v.getWidth(), v.getWidth());

            v.draw(c);

            return b;

        }

        return null;

    }
```

I hope it helps :)

Any query let me know.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! It can solve my problem partially. I can write an onMeasure in the custom view so that I can set the layout-parameters. But a user can drag views (panning) and then the view isn't always on the image.

Comment: Here we are adding the view on Viewgroup right. So even if the user will drag the views all the views upon main viewgroup, so we can get the bitmap for main viewGroup. Still if u have any confusion send sample code i will do for you.

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible since Android system scales down the bitmap.
For ex - if your bitmap size is 480*800 then its size is 480*800*4 = 1536000.
The multiplication with 4 is because each pixel is 4 bytes - RGBA.

Meaning more than a mega and a half for every unscaled image. If the Android won't scale down image you will probably get
OutOfMemoryException after a few image loadings.
as
you have 3 options:

1) view.draw(canvas) you'll get the visible portion of the image(only what is actually being drawn to the screen)

2) getDrawingCache() - will give you the scaled down image.

3) Create custom view which saves the bitmap to the disk and loads it from there when requested